# Find the equation of the tangent line to the graph of the function $f(x)=x(cosx)^2$ when $x=\pi$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$f(x)=x(cosx)^2$

$x=\pi$

Need help solving the question, don't know where to start.

Comment: You know a point on the tangent line, right?  The other information you need is the slope of the tangent line, which you can find by evaluating the derivative of $f(x)$ at that point.  Please make an effort to digest the problem before posting, so that you will better communicate with Readers what response is helpful.

Comment: You may want to have a look here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

you  want the line that passes thorough the point $P=(\pi,f(\pi))$, so that it has equation $y-f(\pi)=m(x-\pi)$,

and the slope must be $m=f'(\pi)$.

Answer (score 1):

First $f(\pi) = \pi (\cos \pi)^2 = \pi$ 
Now $f'(x) = \cos^2 x - 2x \cos x \sin x = \cos^2 x -x \sin 2x$ 
So at $f'(\pi) = 1$
So we obtain:
$y=x+b$, now we plug in the value at the point $(\pi ,\pi)$ to obtain:
$\pi = \pi +b$. Hence $b=0$
So we get the line: $y=x$